# How to record script for putty connected application on Jmeter.

Tags: jmeter, putty

Actually i need to record a script for the application which is connected via putty software.
For opening my application i need to follow below mentioned steps - 
1. Click on Putty.exe icon.
2. Enter Hostname.
3. Select SSH as connection type.
4. click on Save.
4. Click on Open button.
I need to record these all steps using jmeter.
Please help me with feasibility and practicality ...

Answer (score 1):

It is not something you can "record", if you need to execute a command on a remote machine it will make more sense to go for [plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) command from JMeter's [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html)

1. Download [`plink.exe`](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) and drop it somewhere to you local drive
2. Add OS Process Sampler to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   - Command to execute: `cmd`
   - First parameter: `/c`
   - Second parameter: `plink.exe username@hostname -pw password command

For example:

```
c:\jmeter\bin\plink.exe johndoe@localhost -pw secret cowsay "Jmeter is great"
```

[image: JMeter Plink from OS Process Sampler]

The output will be available as normal Sample Result:

[image: JMeter OS Process Sampler Results]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details on kicking off 3rd-party programs from JMeter scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You should add JMeter plugin [SSH Protocol Support](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) and SSH connect without putty.

> SSH Sampler for Jakarta JMeter that executes commands (eg, iostat) over an SSH session, and returns the output

After you add the plugin Add -> Sampler -> SSH Command

And fill the authentication details and write your command in Command field (currently date)

[image]